# Add leading zeroes to a user's input but is being transformed with printf

Tags: bash, shell-script, input, printf, numeric-data

I am currently looking for an alternative to the following code that works a little less 'wonky'.

```
printf "Please enter the ticket number:\t"; read vTICKET; vTICKET=$(printf %04d "$vTICKET"); printf "$vTICKET\n";
```

If I input `072` as the input, this is what I see

```
Please enter the ticket number: 072
0058
```

I am wondering if there is another way I can be a little more forgiving on the input or with the `read` command? `printf` seemed like the cool way to add leading zeroes without actually testing string length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The leading zeros on the input value are causing the shell to interpret it as an octal number.

You can force decimal conversion using `10#` e.g.

```
$ printf "Please enter the ticket number:\t"; read vTICKET; vTICKET=$(printf %04d "$((10#$vTICKET))" ); printf "$vTICKET\n";
Please enter the ticket number: 072
0072
```

Note that in bash, you can assign the results of a `printf` to a variable directly using `-v` e.g. `printf -v vTICKET %04d "$((10#$vTICKET))"`

See also [How do I stop Bash from interpreting octal code instead of integer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406441/how-do-i-stop-bash-from-interpreting-octal-code-instead-of-integer)

Comment: Do we even need `%04d` and the accompanying interpretation?  Wouldn't `%04s` be enough?

Comment: @muru hmm - is zero-padding supported for non-numeric conversion specifiers? I couldn't get that to work for me (bash 4.4.19)

Comment: Ah, it's not portable. On macOS (presumably other BSDs), it works. Seems to based on what `printf(3)` does. Compiling a C file with `printf("%04s", "072");`, I get a warning from `clang` (nothing from GCC 9): ``flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier [-Wformat]``, but it prints `0072` all the same.

Comment: @muru interesting... with both `clang 6.0.0-1ubuntu2` and `gcc 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04`, C printf appears to ignore the `0` and pad to the specified width with spaces

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, you can get rid of any prefixing zeros. After setting on `extglob` first:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
```

You can use `*(0)` after `##` in parameter expansion:

```
$ read -r TICKET; printf "%.4d\n" "${TICKET##*(0)}"
000000000000000000000000000000000000072
0072
```

Once finished, you can go back to normal with `extglob`:

```
$ shopt -u extglob
```

Now `*(0)` undergoes the basic pathname expansion again:

```
$ read -r TICKET; printf "%.4d\n" "${TICKET##*(0)}"
asdfasdf(0)72
0072
$ read -r TICKET; printf "%.4d\n" "${TICKET##*(0)}"
asdfasdf072
bash: printf: asdfasdf072: invalid number
0000
```